# IE 11 - how to detect in .NET

Tags: asp.net, .net, internet-explorer-11

How to detect IE 11 from .NET? I use HttpContext.Current.Request.Browser but over this I don't know how do this. I try this:

```
if (request.Browser.Browser.ToUpper() == "MOZILLA") {
// IE 11.0 User Agent String: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
if (request.UserAgent.Contains("rv:11.0")) {
    ret = eBrowserType.IE;
}
}
```

but I don't like it.

Thanks

Comment: I hate to be "that guy" but how will you you use that info? Your assumption about IE11 may not be correct come IE12.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check for Trident/7.0 which is the new renderer for IE11